# PHP form submits to itself. When clicking on paginating links. All except the Form, vanishes

Tags: php

It is a self-submitting Form. I have 3 independent Select lists whose selected values are passed as the WHERE parameters for the sql query.

When I click on the button, all data are displayed just fine, well LIMITed, and the link pages are below. But:

When I get to click on the page links, the result set and all the links disappear from sight (only the select lists remain in sight). I believe it is related to the isset condition that, if the values have not been set, display the form, if the values have been set, then process the form. So, the first result set displays correctly, but when you try to go to the second page my form interprets that the Select Lists are not set because they are reset and because i have not clicked on the button if i click on the links instead and therefore, it wipes out everything that it not an html Form.

There is no error in the paginating code. The error is in how I link this form with this paginating method. And I can't get to know how I should.

```
        if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) { /***************IF IT IS SET, WE PROCESS THE VALUES*************************/
        $oldcountry = FALSE;
        $oldfrom = FALSE;
        $oldinto = FALSE;

 // Here just checking that all variables have been selected

       if (isset($_POST['country']))


        {
        $oldcountry = $_POST['country'];
        $country = filter_var($oldcountry, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        }
        else {
        echo 'Please, select a country';
        }
        if (isset($_POST['from_language']))
        {
        $oldfrom = $_POST['from_language'];
        $from_language = filter_var($oldfrom, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        }
        else {
        echo 'no has metido el from language';
        }
        if (isset($_POST['into_language']))
        {
        $oldinto = $_POST['into_language'];
        $into_language = filter_var($oldinto, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        }

    // so, once we have selected them and clicked the button, we go for the query

    // and paginate the results


        require_once('bdd1.php');
        $per_page = 6;
        $pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(FName)
        FROM work_assignment, developer
        WHERE AES_DECRYPT(country, 'elperrodesanroquenotienerabo') = '".$country."'
        AND from_language = '".$from_language."'
        AND into_language = '".$into_language."'
        AND work_assignment.developer_id = developer.developer_id
        ORDER BY FName ASC ");
        $pages = ceil (mysql_result($pages_query, 0) /$per_page);
        $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
        $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT FName
        FROM work_assignment, developer
        WHERE AES_DECRYPT(country, 'elperrodesanroquenotienerabo') = '".$country."'
        AND from_language = '".$from_language."'
        AND into_language = '".$into_language."'
        AND work_assignment.developer_id = developer.developer_id
        ORDER BY FName ASC LIMIT $start, $per_page");
        while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        echo '<p>', $query_row['FName'], '</p>';
        }
        if ($pages >=1) {
        for($x = 1; $x <=$pages; $x++){
        echo '<a href="?page='.$x. '">'.$x.'</a> ';
        }
        }
        } /************* END OF IF ISSET TO PROCESS *******************************/

    ?>
```

UPDATE    UPDATE

After all the help, I managed to write a URL string that makes the page links work. Yet, still I need to tweak it as I hardcoded the name of the country (basically Estonia) instead of embedding the variable that represents it, but I can't make that URL properly be written:

This works:

```
echo '<a href="?country=Estonia&from_language=Russian&into_language=Latvian&submitted=true&
page='.$x. '">'.$x.'</a> ';
```

I would just need to replace Estonia by $country, and Russian by $from_language and Latvian by $into_language. But I have tried all possible combinations of single and double quotes and dots and I get syntax errors. Does anybody know how to write that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_POST values are only set if information is sent with a POST request, for example your  has most likely method=POST. When you submit your form with method POST (button=submit) the $_POST values are set. Whenever you klick another link, only a request for a new page will be sent to the server.

If you need the information to be available after the first form submit, you should use a Session. (http://php.net/manual/de/features.sessions.php)
Sessions are stored for each client (webbrowser) and are available until the session times out (please see manual). You would have to set the session variables the first time the form gets submitted. Afterwards you can use the values from the session.

/Edit

If you do not want to use a session, you could add the filter criteria as url parameters (index.php?groupby=country) to the normal links. They would then be accessed with $_GET.

Comment: Alright, the other session variables, not just the ones for the login, ok!

Answer (score 1):

The POST variables are lost because the form isn't submitted when you click the link, just as Slomo pointed out.

Unless you want those values hidden from the user, you may set the form's method to GET instead of POST. That way the variables are added to the URL, just like $_GET['page'].

The links would then have to be rendered in a way that keeps the URL intact except for the page variable, that needs to be changed. It can be done like this (just change currentpage to page):

[A problem of a repeated parameter in the pagination links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981225/a-problem-of-a-repeated-parameter-in-the-pagination-links/2981272#2981272)

Update:

If you want to insert variables inside a string you can either place them inside double quotes (and escape other double quotes inside the string), or concatenate the string and variables, see these two examples:

```
echo "<a href=\"?country=$country&from_language=$from_language&into_language=$into_language&submitted=true&page=$x\">$x</a>";
echo '<a href="?country=' . $country . '&from_language=' . $from_language . '&into_language=' . $into_language . '&submitted=true&page=' . $x . '">' . $x . '</a>';
```

Comment: Thank you everybody. Believe it or not, I have been stuck with this issue for 6 days, at an average of 14 hours a day trying. I will try your solutions tomorrow. Actually it makes more sense to use GET there as I am just requesting data and not entering anything in the database. Also, the data does not contain passwords or so, which I think would be visible in a GET string.

Comment: I am very close to get it as I managed to get the page links working by just hardcoding the name of the country and the from and the into, which I need to replace by their variables. But I always get confused in that syntax. I am including at the bottom of the updated code, the url